# ngrx 8 selector in a effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have to use a selector in an effects.

I've tried with this code but it doesn't work, and I don't see what's wrong.

```
loadAccountUpdateProducts$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProducts),
  concatMap(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectMarketAccountData)))
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(([action, data]) =>
    this.service
      .postAccountUpdateProducts(action.products, data.account)
      .pipe(
        map(data => MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProductsSuccess({ data })),
        catchError(error =>
          of(MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProductsFailure({ error }))
        )
      )
  )
)
);
```

### Update

Now it works I've mistaken the service signature. The only thing I don't like is typing `const dto = store as MarketAccountCompleteDto`. Is there a better way?

```
loadAccountUpdateProducts$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProducts),
  concatMap(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectMarketAccountData)))
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(([action, store]) => {
    const dto = store as MarketAccountCompleteDto;
    return this.service
      .postAccountUpdateProducts({
        user: dto.account,
        products: action.products
      })
      .pipe(
        map(data =>
          MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProductsSuccess({ data })
        ),
        catchError(error =>
          of(
            MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProductsFailure({ error })
          )
        )
      );
  })
)
);
```

### Update 2

It works also with

```
loadAccountUpdateProducts$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProducts),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectMarketAccountData))),
  mergeMap(([action, store]) => {
    const dto = store as MarketAccountCompleteDto;
    return this.service
      .postAccountUpdateProducts({
        user: dto.account,
        products: action.products
      })
      .pipe(
        map(data =>
          MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProductsSuccess({ data })
        ),
        catchError(error =>
          of(
            MarketActions.loadMarketAccountUpdateProductsFailure({ error })
          )
        )
      );
  })
)
);
```

Comment: What doesn’t work? On first glance this looks fairly okay although it could be done without the of(action)...

Comment: I've a bunch of errors :(

Comment: `data` is a shadowed name. You are using it as 2nd array field as well as map-callback

Comment: Thanks very much for the help :) I've update the thread now it works :) waiting a better way to type const dto = store as MarketAccountCompleteDto;

Comment: @MikeOne what's about UPDATE2 ?

Comment: Looks good! For the typing you can do this: ([action, store] :[any, MarketAccountCompleteDto ])

Comment: The different between Update 1 and Update 2 is that in Update 2 your selector `selectMarketAccountData` will be executed as soon as the effect is created and subscribed. With Update 1, the selector will only be executed when an `loadMarketAccountUpdateProducts` action is dispatched.